# What is the workflow to manage git branch history appropriately when working on 3+ branches simultaneously?

Tags: git, github

Summarized Question: What is the proper workflow in git for dealing with multiple people working on multiple branches at the same time, on overlapping sets of files, where changes don't come in chronological order?

Given Branch A and B are sitting in pull request stage and branch Z has been merged to master already, what is the correct workflow to begin a Branch C development that requires features from Z, except for a few better files from B, which are destined to overtake Z's changes, but just haven't been through the pull request to make it to master yet.

Steps to re-create the situation in question

1. Clone the github project to my local computer.
2. Make a new branch A and make changes, commit, push to origin branch of same name on github, make pull request
3. Make a new branch B and make changes, commit, push to origin branch of same name on github, make a pull request
4. In the meantime, someone has made a branch Z, pushed to origin branch, and already merged the pull request.
5. How do I develop feature C which requires Z and B? Caveat is Z and B contain modifications to the same files. For some files, I want the Z edition. For others, I want the B edition.

What are the right steps here to begin working on feature C? I know I need Z and B to do it. Should I do a git pull on my local master to pick up Z, make a branch C, then merge B to C? I tried this, but it doesn't work as the older files from B take over the changes I want from Z. Is there a way to handpick that I want the changes from Z except for a couple files, which I want to get from the branch B: changefromb.c, changefromb.h.

Or am I doing it wrong? Now that a bunch of us are pushing things daily, I'm finding I don't know which features of git handle this appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the easiest way to solve this problem is making my own ahead of master branch, which pulls from the real master but also contains latest code not yet in master. I've been calling the branch master-dev.

Answer (score 1):

`git checkout` allows you to select the files you want:

```
git checkout B changefromb.c # places B's copy of changefromb.c into current branch
```

If you want to have the exact copy of B's files to create C, I would create a branch C from branch Z and use the above command to copy over the relevant changes from B.

Otherwise, if you want to copy over changes from B and apply them on top of the existing version of Z, you can use [cherry-picking](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) to select specific commits from B to copy over to the new branch C. Depending on how "atomic" the commits are, you may have to create a separate "clean-up" commit to undo unrelated changes from the cherry-picked commits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "git flow". People have asked themselves the same question and came up with this great methodology for managing work on multiple branches.

https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/

The tutorial explains it perfectly.